# ASCII code not working in firefox but on chrome working fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, ascii

I had created function which allows to enter all characters and almost all symbols on chrome and that is working fine but on firefox I am not able to enter any character or any symbols

Below is my script

```
  function blockSpecialChar(e) {
    var k = e.keyCode;
    return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || (k > 31 && k < 34) || (k > 34 && k < 38) || k == 8 || k == 64 || k == 95 || k == 61 || k == 63 || (k > 39 && k <= 57));
}
```

.aspx code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtdescribe"  onkeypress="return blockSpecialChar(event)" CssClass="input" ValidationGroup="services" runat="server" MaxLength="255"></asp:TextBox>
```

This function restricts only html symbols to insert but on firefox it is not allowing to insert character also

Example on chrome

[image]

Example on firefox

[image]

Comment: I think you need to give more information. This is pretty vague. It isn't clear exactly what isn't working. Show example input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: Information is ok?

Comment: I don't think that problem has to do with the function. How are you using the function?

Comment: @Carcigenicate 
 
on key press I am using the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function blockSpecialChar(e) {    
        if (e == 60 || e == 62 || e == 34 || e == 38 || e == 39) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }    
}

onClick="ToggelDiv(this.id); Specialinstruction();"
```

These will be work on all browsers.